# Is there a way to access HTTP headers in a Java EE interceptor?

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, header, ejb, interceptor

I have a JSP page that invokes an EJB method and I am using a Java EE interceptor for the EJB method. So the method checkHeaders of the interceptor will be executed before the EJB method

My question is: How can I access the HTTP headers in the interceptor method?

My application is running in JBOSS 6.1

```
// interceptor class


@AroundInvoke
public Object checkHeaders(InvocationContext invocationContext)
            throws Exception {

    // I need something here to access the HTTP headers:    
         invocationContext.getHTTPHeaders();
    .....
 //do something with the headers

//continue execution
invocationContext.proceed();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it is a bad smell to have a dependency on web APIs from the service layer. Why do you need the headers? Authentication/authorization I would guess?

Comment: Yes, I need the header for authn/authz.

Comment: IF you use Spring, you can get username and granted permissions inside an interceptor with `Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to access some HTTP request specific attributes in service layer (i.e. in EJB) until you explicitly pass them to EJB method. So if you really need it, you can add extra parameter to your EJB method, like `List<String> headers` or `Map<String, String> headers` and read parameter value in your interceptor:

```
      public Object checkHeaders(InvocationContext context) throws
        Exception{

          if (ctx.getMethod().getName().equals("yourTargetMethod")) {
              // assume your 'headers' parameter is first method param
              List<String> headers = (List<String>) ctx.getParameters()[0]);
          }
      }
```

Comment: Well, this is what I did and it worked:  I added this to checkHeaders method:HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext
     .getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"); My understanding is that the interceptor executes in the same security context as the intercepted class/method

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the HTTP headers from and EJB Interceptor because the EJB container is independent of the web tier. You would either pass the headers into your EJB method call and check them as part of its business logic or perform the check in the JSP/web tier. I would go with the latter since you won't be leaking web concerns / dependencies into your business/EJB tier.